# Mysql Multiple use of Date_Format

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently using

```
$resultc = mysql_query( "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(Tender_Return_Date,'%d/%m/%Y') AS Tender_Return_Date FROM Est_Ind_Client 
LEFT JOIN Est_Ind_Client_Notes ON Est_Ind_Client.C_ID=Est_Ind_Client_Notes.Ind_C_FK 
WHERE Ind_FK='{$row["EI_ID"]}'" );
```

As part of the above statement, I have two further date fields being "Date_Received" and "Company_Return_Date" which I also wish to format in the same way as above. I have tried repeating the format statement but receive errors from the MYSQL query. I have looked online for a solution but the only examples include for formatting one date as above and I require multiple occurances

Any guidance would be great.

Comment: there is no problem at all to use multiple calls of date_format like `select date_format(col1) as d1, date_format(col2) as d2` and so on. show us your problematic query.

Comment: When I use multiple I get an error of "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in...."

Comment: yes, this is because sql query is wrong (and you are not using mysql_error() to handle the error), so post what query you have written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right, you need this:

```
SELECT *, 
    DATE_FORMAT(Tender_Return_Date,'%d/%m/%Y') AS Tender_Return_Date, 
    DATE_FORMAT(Date_Received,'%d/%m/%Y') AS Date_Received,
    DATE_FORMAT(Company_Return_Date,'%d/%m/%Y') AS Company_Return_Date
 FROM Est_Ind_Client 
 LEFT JOIN Est_Ind_Client_Notes ON Est_Ind_Client.C_ID=Est_Ind_Client_Notes.Ind_C_FK 
 WHERE Ind_FK='{$row["EI_ID"]}'"
```

Comment: This is effectively what I tried, however I get the error "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in" and then the line of the code

Comment: I found the issue, I was missing a join to another table which houses the date_received column. Thank you for your help