# Multiple date_format conversions

Tags: mysql, date-format

I'm trying to use multiple date_format conversions from YYYY-MM-DD to DD-MM-YYYY.

When I use one it works:

```
"SELECT *,
DATE_FORMAT(DOB, '%d-%m-%Y') AS DOB
FROM Basics");
```

However when I use two it stops working:

```
"SELECT *,
DATE_FORMAT(DOB, '%d-%m-%Y') AS DOB,
DATE_FORMAT(Shearing-Date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS Shearing-Date
FROM Basics");
```

I tried this fix but it didn't work: [Mysql Multiple use of Date_Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37225928/mysql-multiple-use-of-date-format)

I also tried AND but that didn't work.

What am I doing wrong? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely incorrect identifier:

```
SELECT *,
  DATE_FORMAT(DOB, '%d-%m-%Y') AS DOB,
  DATE_FORMAT(`Shearing-Date`, '%d-%m-%Y') AS `Shearing-Date`
FROM Basics
```

If you are using `-` as a part of a name it should be quoted with backtick.